# Searching for a specific window lock

Tags: windows

I recently moved into a new place and almost all the window locks are broken and these windows are single hung and are located on the ground level. I have looked numerous places but I cannot find a similar lock and I cannot locate window manufacturer information. Can anyone tell from my picture what kind of lock this is or where I could find it?

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a sash or a casement window latch. Try looking for "antique sash window latch" or "antique casement latch"

Comment: @shufler: Yep, that's what it looks like. Usually they're used to tie the two sashes of the window together (and to apply a bit of pressure to help them make a good seal). I've never seen one used this way, but I suppose it would work...

Comment: **"almost all the window locks are broken"** - Perhaps that's a clue that, rather than trying to find similar units to match the few that are not broken yet, in an inappropriate use of hardware, you should replace them all with hardware suited to the use...just a thought.

Comment: Agreed with @Ecnerwal.  These appear to be sash locks that are installed incorrectly.  They are designed to push the sash down tightly as they are turned. I'm guessing they are breaking because they are not exerting pressure in a direction that allows any movement.

Answer (score 1):

This type of locking mechanism is a sash latch. From the picture it looks like it's not installed in the way sash latches are typically installed.

Usually this type of latch is attached to one of the sashes of the window. Here is such a latch on one of my sash windows:

[image: A contemporary sash window latch]

You can see it's not installed into the frame like yours, instead it's on the end of one of the sashes and latches into a bit installed on the other sash. In some windows, like my basement windows (not pictured) both sashes slide, in this window I took pictures of, only one side slides. Here's a better look at the lock's position within the entire window:

[image: A contemporary sliding sash window]

As you already know, your particular latch is older and while you will probably have difficulty finding this exact model from a retailer you will likely find modern equivalents that may fit. As @keshlam, and @Comintern noted in the comments technically this latch is not appropriate for your window. Buying a new latch and installing it into the frame in the same way as your old latches could result in them breaking the same way. If you go with this approach I would recommend that you search online or bring the latch with you to a store to find a new latch that matches in dimensions and see if you can find something made out of a durable material.

Another approach that @Ecnerwal mentioned: there's no rule that says you need to use the same style of latch. If you're not keen on replacing the entire window(s), you can buy latches that are appropriate for your style of window. From your picture it's not clear if your windows are sash windows (they slide open) or casement windows (they open outwards on a hinge). My guess is they are casement windows in which case there are many options available to you. Again, you can search online or bring your window measurements to a store to find latches that will fit and suit your style.